# Log Each Request And Output In EC2 Ubuntu or Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance and in this instance, I have some cron jobs.
This cron jobs looks like:

```
0 5 * * mon curl -Ssi -X POST http://example.com
```

And I have some manual outputs like:

```
echo "output: hello..."
```

I want to store these actions on a log file in EC2 ubuntu or linux instance. Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Expected output:

```
[2021-10-10 ...] - POST http://example.com
[2021-10-11 ...] - output: hello...
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following script `~/bin/site-detector`

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile

log_file=/tmp/site-detector.log
curl -Ssi -X POST http://example.com  >> $log_file
echo "Detected @ $(date)" >> $log_file
echo " " >> $log_file
```

Make your script executable:

```
chmod a+x ~/bin/site-detector
```

Update your crontab script:

```
0 5 * * mon ~/bin/site-detector
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my crontab includes several requests.  `0 5 * * mon curl -Ssi -X POST http://example.com ; 0 * */1 * mon curl -Ssi -X POST http://example1.com ; 0 5 * * mon curl -Ssi -X POST http://example2.com... ` Is this an effective way?

Comment: Crontab configuration is about the scheduling and timing. `~/bin/site-detector` script is about functionality. Put all your functionality in scirpt, put all your scheduling and timing in crontab line.